# Как удалить текст между двумя символами в строке

Tags: java

Как удалить текст между двумя символами, например здесь, из "Впрочем, английский текст !комментария! составлен правильно." получить  "Впрочем, английский текст составлен правильно."

```
 public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String s = "Впрочем, английский текст !комментария! составлен правильно.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть ваши попытки решения проблемы, тем не менее сразу подскажу, что вы можете использовать регулярные выражения для решения данной задачи (в частности, метод класса `String`: `replaceAll`).

Comment: у вас никогда не будет больше 2х восклицательных знаков в тексте? Как вы решите вот такую проблему? `"Впрочем, английский текст !комме!нтария! составлен правильно."`

Answer (score 2):

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Впрочем, английский текст !комментария! составлен правильно.";
        String[] buff = s.split("!");
        String result = buff[0] + buff[2];
        
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

данный код будет работать если у вас только 2 знака восклицания в тексте, но он очень простой.

Answer (score 1):

Как было указано в комментариях, следует использовать `String::replaceAll`, в котором в качестве первого аргумента нужно указать регулярное выражение типа такого `(\![^!]\!\s*)`, т.е. текст из любых символов кроме `!` между двумя восклицательными знаками, за которым следует 0 или больше пробельных символов `\s*`, второй аргумент -- пустая строка:

```java
String s = "!Comment! Впрочем, английский текст !комментария! составлен правильно!!COMMENT!";

System.out.println("'" + s.replaceAll("(\\![^!]+\\!\\s*)", "") + "'");
// -> 'Впрочем, английский текст составлен правильно!'
```